# Appsheet Build - my push notifications working in apk but not working in aab

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, google-appsheet

My application build seems to get push notifications when downloaded from APK on android. The AAB bundle that was on the same email app sheet sent with links, is the one uploaded onto play store. The play store downloaded app from android is not sending push notifications.

I tried pushing another release and still same issue. But seems to work perfectly fine with the APK not AAB. I even tried converting the APK to AAB to upload but had integrity app issues.

Comment: It seems like an issue with the signing. Make sure that you are signing the app bundle with the same key set that you use to sign the apk.